Arm Cortex-M7 SAM-E70 x32-ld is keeping both weak and strong function definition
I am trying basic thing with SAM-E70 but proper documentation is not existing and after 6 hours not even GPT could help, so I am asking here. I need to be able to place function directly at vector table. If function is not defined, default weak unused ISR will be used. I can't place ISR functions inside structure. They must be separated. I took Reset_Handler as example:
I have two fp definitions, one in interrupts.c:
__attribute__((weak, section(".pfnReset"))) void (*const interrupts_reset)(void) = UnusedIsrHandler; 

second one in startup_xc32.c:
__attribute__((section(".pfnReset"))) void (*const interrupts_reset)(void) = &Reset_Handler;

this is output form .map file:
 *(.pfnReset.*)
 .pfnReset.interrupts_reset
                0x0000000000400004        0x4 build/default/production/_ext/1083072663/interrupts.o
 .pfnReset.interrupts_reset
                0x0000000000400008        0x4 build/default/production/_ext/1294464586/startup_xc32.o
                0x0000000000400008                interrupts_reset

and this is srec file, from start of vector table (address 400000), the F0FF4520 is address of stack pointer init value, after which both function addresses are placed:
    S2 14 400000 F0FF4520 E5B54000 015B4000 E5B54000 07
                         ^        ^
                         |        |
address of weak function |        |
                                  |
       address of strong function |

finally here is my linker script:
SECTIONS
{
    .vectors :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sfixed = .;
        __svectors = .;
        KEEP(*(.pvStack.*))               /* Stack pointer */
        KEEP(*(.pfnReset.*))              /* Reset Vector */
        KEEP(*(.pfnNonMaskableInt.*))     /* Non-Maskable Interrupt */
        KEEP(*(.pfnHardFault.*))            /* Hard Fault */
        KEEP(*(.pfnMemoryManagement.*))     /* Memory Management Fault */
        KEEP(*(.pfnBusFault.*))             /* Bus Fault */
        KEEP(*(.pfnUsageFault.*))           /* Usage Fault */
        KEEP(*(.pfnReservedC9.*))           /* Reserved */
        KEEP(*(.pfnReservedC8.*))           /* Reserved */
        KEEP(*(.pfnReservedC7.*))           /* Reserved */
        ...
        } > VECTOR_REGION

Why the function is not replaced, but both are used? (toolchain XC32 v4.40)

It could set them as alias and then references would be discarded.  Ie, not a function pointer.  The space allocated by the function pointer is not 'weak', so it must remain in the binary.  So, you have to look at external uses of  interrupts_reset and see which variant they link to.  For example, void UnusedIsrHandler(); extern void __attribute__ ((weak, section(".pfnReset"), alias ("UnusedIsrHandler"))) interrupts_reset();, but the 'UnusedIsrHandler() still needs to be defined.  Now GPT will know and be smarter than you next time.  But GPT seldom disagrees, it only tries to answer.

The problem with weak aliases is that I have to define a functions with the same name, but my ISR functions have different names. I could create wrapper functions for this but this is unwanted solution for me. I want to just take a function address and assign it to specific place in memory.

You are decoding the srecord file incorrectly. It should be S2 14 440000 and so on. So there is no making sense of this. Typos?

@Lundin fixed, thanks for noticing, I just put spaces in wrong places.

Now what happens if you expose these variables in a shared header like extern __attribute__((section(".pfnReset"))) void (*const interrupts_reset)(void);? Otherwise I suspect they end up as tentative definitions in different translatation units and so the linker has no reason to replace one with the other, as there are no naming collisions present.

@Lundin I tried without a success, but if I remove week from first one I get linker error, so the linker knows about them. I am suspecting this is not possible to do in this way. Probably linker will use strong definition in case when the function pointer should be used, but I am only storing it.

Are optimizations enabled and, if so, which ones? I.e. which -O (if any) are you passing to compiler? Are link-time optimizations (-flto) enabled?

Okay so after many hours I finally run out of ways how to do it wrong. The key was to use EXTERN() command and place both function pointers into section not marked as KEEP. From MPLAB® XC32 Assembler, Linker and Utilities User's Guide :
The EXTERN(symbol symbol ...) command forces symbol to be entered in the output file as an
undefined symbol. Doing this may, for example, trigger linking of additional modules from standard
libraries. Several symbols may be listed for each EXTERN, and EXTERN may appear multiple times.
This command has the same effect as the -u command line option.
Pity alias do not work across translation units, overwise it would be perfect solution.
